# SQL Server - How to know to which database user certificate is mapped to?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2017, certificate, signature, database-user

Inside a user database, I have two certificates, both are used for signing stored procedures

> First cert was created long time ago by someone
>   Second I created myself for testing purposes

For second cert I also created database user from certificate

When I query `sys.certificates`, I can see column `[sid]`

For the second cert I can find this `[sid]` in the `sys.database_principals` and can see which database user second cert is mapped to (which is the user I created)

> When I do the same for first cert (created by someone long time ago),
>   this cert's [sid] can't be found in the sys.database_principals

Question: how do I find out which database user first cert is mapped to ?

Comment: Perhaps the user created from the certificate has since been dropped.

Comment: Following @DanGuzman thought, if you happen to have an old backup of that database, you might be able to check if a user with that sid existed.